# Can't create elevator using waypoints in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script for waypoints, which I find [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/429623/enemy-movement-from-waypoint-to-waypoint.html). It works fine for objects, which move on the **horizontal** axes. But it don't move objects up and down. Can't understand, why.

Elevator are just decoration and it will randomly move from one floor to another.

```
public Transform[] waypoint;    // The amount of Waypoint you want
 float patrolSpeed = 3.0f;       // The walking speed between Waypoints
 float dampingLook = 6.0f;       // How slowly to turn
 public float pauseDuration;     // How long to pause at a Waypoint

 float curTime;
 int  currentWaypoint;
 CharacterController character;

 void Start()
 {
     character = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
 }

 void Update()
 {
     if (currentWaypoint < waypoint.Length)
         Patrol();
     else
         currentWaypoint = 0;
 }

 void Patrol()
 {
     Vector3 target = waypoint[currentWaypoint].position;
     target.y = transform.position.y;    // Keep waypoint at character's height
     Vector3 moveDirection = target - transform.position;

     if(moveDirection.magnitude < 0.5)
     {
         if (curTime == 0)
             curTime = Time.time;        // Pause over the Waypoint
         if ((Time.time - curTime) >= pauseDuration)
         {
             currentWaypoint = Random.Range(0, waypoint.Length);
             curTime = 0;
         }
     }
     else
     {        
         var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(target - transform.position);
         transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * dampingLook);
         character.Move(moveDirection.normalized * patrolSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
     }    
 }
```

**Edit1:**

Here is the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OqRB3_nYWS4&feature=youtu.be) how it works.

Comment: What happens when you run the script? Is the object moving at all? Is it facing the correct direction?

Comment: Do you have any rigidbodies? Do they have "Use Gravity" active?

Comment: Yes, it move from one point to another, but only if horizontal coordinates are different for this points. If only vertical coordinates are different, object just stay at one place.

Comment: @PatrickvD Elevators have rigidbody, but gravitation disabled, because else it just fall down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, without a rigidbody:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Elevator : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform[] waypoint;    // The amount of Waypoint you want
    float patrolSpeed = 3.0f;       // The walking speed between Waypoints
    float dampingLook = 6.0f;       // How slowly to turn
    public float pauseDuration;     // How long to pause at a Waypoint
    float curTime;
    int  currentWaypoint;
    void Update()
    {
        if (currentWaypoint < waypoint.Length)
            Patrol();
        else
            currentWaypoint = 0;
    }

    void Patrol()
    {
        Vector3 target = waypoint[currentWaypoint].position;
        Vector3 moveDirection = target - transform.position;
        if(moveDirection.magnitude < 0.5)
        {
            if (curTime == 0)
                curTime = Time.time;        // Pause over the Waypoint
            if ((Time.time - curTime) >= pauseDuration)
            {
                currentWaypoint = Random.Range(0, waypoint.Length);
                curTime = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            transform.Translate(moveDirection.normalized * patrolSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }   
    }
}
```

Edit: Correct the script by removing two rotation lines.

Comment: Now it moves really strange =) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xetlb0k1Aj8&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to delete the two rotation lines.